# Assign multiple values to array via parse_str

Tags: php, arrays, string, parsing

I know that you can add values to an array via `parse_str()` like so:

```
parse_str( 'a[]=1&a[]=2&a[]=3' );
parse_str( 'a[0]=1&a[1]=2&a[2]=3' );
```

These both produce:

```
Array (
  [0] => 1
  [1] => 2
  [2] => 3
)
```

I'm looking to produce an array sort of like this:

```
parse_str( 'a[]=1,2,3' );
```

Is there any way of doing this, so that I don't need to type `a[i]=` every single time?

Comment: I would not use `parse_str()`, is a potential security hole.

Comment: Unreliable input can cause bugs, and untrusted input can overwrite even superglobals, e.g.: `parse_str('_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]=/tmp')` which would be a pretty bad thing if later on you want to refer to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` for some other purpose like checking folder security.

Comment: What exactly is the use-case here? Where would `'a[]=1,2,3'` come from?

Comment: The fact that you expressed concern about typing suggests that you are creating this manually. If that's the case, why are you not using `$a=array(1,2,3);` or `$a=array('1','2','3');`

Comment: Yes, I am creating this manually. I'm parsing lines from a text file in order to list conjugations of Spanish verbs in the most efficient way possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't use `parse_str()`**, not  unless you're *very* sure about what you're doing. (Explained below.) Instead, I would suggest something like JSON, which doesn't change unexpected variables, is fairly fast, standardized, and easier to generate/consume.

```
$str = '{"items":[1,2,3]}'
$obj = json_decode($data);

var_export($obj->items);
```

Yields:

```
 array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 3,
)
```

### "Why not parse_str?"

1. Bad input can easily break your code by overwriting variables you don't expect
2. Malicious input can introduce security risks.

For example, try this:

```
$input = '_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]=/foo';
parse_str($input);
echo($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

Wow, someone managed to change one of the variables that was storing server-configuration data. This could easily break stuff like content-management code that will then save files to the wrong place, or to bypass "must be a subfolder of" checks.

Comment: Don't use `parse_str()` without the second argument would be better advice :)

Comment: Fair enough, but I'd still argue it's ancient and syntactically barbaric :p JSON also offers Marcus the terse `1,2,3` style he's asking for.

Comment: It's very useful in situations where you need to decode a given url.

Comment: @Jack The query portion, I suppose, but the other 99% of the time the stuff you want is already in `$_GET`.

Comment: As with anything, you need to know *when* to use something.